# Table row spacing - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table developed with bootstrap. How can I put a spacing between each table row?

What I want is something like this:

[image]

**My code**

[codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/Dk2GoZPmde)

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-borderless">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the below CSS.

```
.table {
        border-spacing:35px;
        border-collapse: separate;
    }
```

```css
.table {
    border-spacing:35px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-borderless">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to split the lines so that the background is visible between their space? 
As my picture shows

Comment: If you notice my image, between each table row is spaced with the background color of the page, gray type. Is it possible to apply this effect or to split each row of the table completely?

Comment: see codepen link : https://codepen.io/foramtrada232/pen/rNNgvdx

Comment: Perfect !! Thanks !!